# Evaluate the following boundless improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Alright I think I am confusing myself over this problem. Its relatively simple but I'm getting caught up during the actual evaluation
So the problem is $\displaystyle{\int_2^3}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}}dx$. I know how to solve for it but its an improper integral since 3 makes it shoot off to infinite. So I think your supposed to make this into a limit. $\lim_{c\to 3} $ When you apply the fundamental theorem from my work I get $\lim_{c\to 3} $$(-2\sqrt{3-c} + 2)$. Final answer is two. Now this is a very elementary question but why is it two. Im assuming they just plugged 3 in for c and got 2 which makes sense. But is this not at all affected by the fact as c approaches 3 its infinite? I think I have a mis understanding cause I want to plug infinite into for c which I know is not valid but why is it not valid

Comment: Are you comfortable with the fact that integrals like $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$ can be finite?

Answer (score 1):

We are looking at the function $f(x)=-2\sqrt{3-x}$, which is continuous and well-defined for $x\leq 3$ (its domain). Thus $$\int_{2}^{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}}dx=f(3)-f(2)=2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried integration by substitution?

Start by setting $u=3-x$ and then changing the upper and lower limits using that substition

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is about. The author obviously got the right answer, but he is interested in understanding why the answer makes sense.